# Android Multi-Page Registration Form

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making an android app with Login System and it is connected to Firebase as its backend in Android Studio. How can I create a Multi-page registration?
I am thinking about when the user clicks the Sign-Up button it will go to another activity that asks their **Gender** and then after they selected their gender, it will go to another activity that asks their **profile picture**.

**Activities**

Select Gender >> Select Profile Picture >> User Informations then register.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the information filled in the current activity plus the information recieved from the previous activity to the next activity using intent. At the last activity you shall have all the form data which yiu can submit

Or you can have a singleton class to hold all the information to which every activity can right the data. At the end you can use this singleton to sign up the user.

EDIT
To create a singleton in Kotlin:

```
object class FormData {
    var name: String = ""
    ....
}
```

Then in all your activities you can write data to this singleton whenever user press next

```
FormData.name = nameEditText.text
```

Comment: The idea you shared seems to work but since I don't have deep knowledge of Android Development yet, do you have any links that I can follow along. I like the idea of the singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

**Assume that you have written two or more Activity classes, (ex ActivityA and ActivityB)**

**To pass data between two activities**, you should use an Intent class via which you are starting the Activity and before startActivity for ActivityB. In your case, it should be,

```
val intent = Intent(this@ActivityA, ActivityB::class.java)
intent.putExtra("Username","John")
startActivity(intent)
```

Now in ActivityB, you can write a code to catch the Intent that pass by the previous activity. (ActivityB)

```
var profileName=intent.getStringExtra("Username")
```

if you want, you can create a global variable and set the value, It will allow you to access that value inside your whole class. I think this will help you.